# writing a Jacada Interaction extension

Tags: callback, extension-methods, interaction

I want to create an "extension" for a Jacada Interaction (to extend functionality), in my case to parse and assign the numerical part of serialNumber (a letter, followed by digits) to a numeric global ("system") variable, say serialNumeric.  What I am lacking is the structure and syntax to make this work, including the way to reference interaction variables from within the extension.

Here is my failed attempt, with lines commented out to make it innocuous after failing; I think I removed "return page;" after crashing, whereupon it still crashed:

```
initExtensions("serialNumeric", function(app){
    app.registerExtension("loaded", function(ctx, page) {
        // Place your extension code here
        //$('[data-refname="snum"]').val('serialNumber');        
        // snum = Number(substring(serialNumber,1))
    });
});
```

Here is an example of one that works:

```
/**
 * Description: Add swiping gestures to navigate the next/previous pages 
 */
initExtensions("swipe", function(app) {
    // Swipe gestures (mobile only)
    app.registerExtension('pageRenderer', function(ctx, page) {
        page.swipe(function(evt) {            
            (evt.swipestart.coords[0] - evt.swipestop.coords[0] > 0)  
                ? app.nextButton.trigger('click')
                : app.backButton.trigger('click')
        });
        return page;
    });
});
```

After reading the comment below, I tried the following, unsuccessfully (the modified question variable is not written back to that variable).  It rendered poorly in the comment section, so I am putting it here:

```
    initExtensions("serialNumeric", function(app){
        app.registerExtension("loaded", function(ctx, page) {
            var sernum = new String($('[data-refname="enter"] input'));
            var snumeric = new String(sernum.substr(1));
            $('[data-refname="enter"] input').val(snumeric);
        });
    });
```

I would like to understand when this code will run: it seems logical that it would run when the variable is assigned.  Thanks for any insight ~

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you extend `loaded` event. You don't have to return the page from the extension like in your working example below.

The `page` argument contains the DOM of the page you have just loaded, the `ctx` argument contains the data of the page in JSON form. You can inspect the content of both arguments in the browser's inspection tools. I like Chrome. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on Mac.

The selector `$('[data-refname="snum"] input')` will get you the input field from the question with the name `snum` that you defined in the designer. You can then place the value in the input field with the value from the `serialNumber` variable.

```
$('[data-refname="snum"] input').val(serialNumber);
```

You can also read values in the same way.

You can't (at this point) access interaction variables in the extension, unless you place theses variables inside question fields.

Comment: I have set up a test interaction with one question element leading to a statement element that displays the question variable.  What I have written below fails to make the assignment to the question variable.  Can you point out what I have done wrong?  Many thanks.  Here's what isn't working:
initExtensions("serialNumeric", function(app){   
    app.registerExtension("loaded", function(ctx, page) {
        var sernum = new String($('[data-refname="enter"] input'));
        var snumeric = new String(sernum.substr(1));
        $('[data-refname="enter"] input').val(snumeric);
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

Here is a  simple example how to put your own value programmatically into a input field and cause it to read it into the model, so upon next it will be sent to the server. You are welcome to try more sophisticated selectors to accommodate for your own form.

```js
initExtensions("sample", function(app){
    
    app.registerExtension("loaded", function(ctx, page) {        
        // simple selector
        var i = $('input');        
        // set new value
        i.val('some new value');
        // cause trigger so we can read into our model
        i.trigger('change');
    });    
   
});
```